# Exclude property using mvn versions:update-properties with excludesList

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-versions-plugin, scalatest-maven-plugin

I'm using `mvn versions:update-properties -DexcludesList=org.scalatest:scalatest*` to exclude update of property `scalatest.version` inside pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <scalatest.version>3.0.5</scalatest.version>
</properties>
```

But after running the command `scalatest.version` is updated to `3.3.0-SNAP2` version which is the [latest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest).

How to use `-DexcludesList` argument correctly? I followed the [docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html#excludesList)

The only workaround i found is excluding `SNAP2` versions in `rules.xml` like below:

```
<ruleset xmlns="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" comparisonMethod="maven" xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0 http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd">
    <ignoreVersions>
        <ignoreVersion type="regex">9.*</ignoreVersion>
        <ignoreVersion type="regex">6.1.*</ignoreVersion>
        <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*SNAP.*</ignoreVersion>
    </ignoreVersions>
    <rules>
    </rules>
</ruleset>
```

And running `mvn versions:update-properties  -Dmaven.version.rules=file:////tmp/rules.xml -DexcludesList=org.scalatest:scalatest*`

This way `scalatest` is updated to `3.2.2`. I'd like to ignore update of `scalatest` version completely.

Tried different variations: `-DexcludesList=org.scalatest:scalatest:*`, `-DexcludesList=org.scalatest:scalatest:*:*:*` to no avail.

Using version 2.1 of `versions-maven-plugin`, updated to latest `2.8.1` and still `scalatest` was updated.

Comment: yes, same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use `-DexcludeProperties=scalatest.version` argument.

`mvn versions:update-properties -DexcludeProperties=scalatest.version` achieved what i needed.

The [docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html#excludeProperties)